# django request distant database

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to request, in a django project "FIRST", an existing database for an other django project "SECOND" witch are deployed in two differents machines.
I need to get in app 1 the values of an attribute's modele in app5 (as explained below).
I've search "how django requests distant database" but i didn't found an answer to my question

Thank you,

Machine 1 (192.xxx.xx.xx) :

```
     ----- project FIRST 
                    ------APP1
                    ------APP2
```

Machine 2 (192.yyy.yy.yy) :

```
     ----- project SECOND 
                    ------APP3
                    ------APP4
                    ------APP5
```

Comment: you need to create API in second app to access it in first app

Comment: or add app5 to project FIRST and [route your database calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) to use the other database for app5 (making sure it doesn't allow any migrations).

Comment: How distant is the machine? In ms round trip time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used dirkgroten's solution. It works for me on test plateform (with docker's container).

The steps I folow :

- create à new django app with the same name that the App5 in project "FIRST".
- copy, in the models.py (e.i: FIRST/app5/models.py), only tables and fields that I need to get from SECOND/app5.models.py
- add the new 'app5' in INSTALLED_APP in the FIRST/settings.py
- add, in the DATABASES of the FIRST/settings.py, the definition of parameters witch let the project connect to the distant database.
- add the route database in the routers.py file
- Don't forget to import the models of the new app5 in app1

note that if your tables hav other tables debendencies from the models.py you have to add them too in the new models.py

I gess that I haven't forget any other step

Thank's to every one for your responses

(PS: SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH)

Answer (score 0):

You need a RESTful API.

A big topic, and I actually just answered it for another person.

I suggest you [check it out here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500246/django-send-a-post-request-through-form-to-another-server/55502006#55502006)

Once you make your API's, you can make some admin actions that go fetch the data, and populate your new database with the values of the old.

At least that's one way of doing it.