# Django: Send a Post Request Through Form to Another Server

Tags: django, post

I have a form on a template on my domain1 and want to send a POST request to domain2. I am using Django as the framework. I only want domain2 to accept requests from domain1 and domain2 (itself). However, I run into csrf problems.

Comment: without the actual code that produces the issue and more detail about the error, we're not going to be able to help. can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: and what about @csrf_exempt?

Comment: I don't want @csrf_exempt because I want to ONLY allow post requests sent from domain1 or domain2

Comment: but are both domains being served by the same django app?

Comment: Right now, one domain is localhost:5000 and the other is localhost:8000. They are two different web apps.

Comment: and what's the exact error you get?

Comment: Refused to display 'localhost:5000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.  I have one as an 5000 as an iframe embedded in 8000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191177/discussion-between-coderocks-and-dirkgroten).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a RESTful API. That's a very large topic and would be dumb/impossible to do the work for you here with the info I've been given, so here's a summary.

I suggest [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for making api's.

What the above means, is that when you want to do this sort of stuff *(POST requests from other domains),* you need a token. This is usually done with a ***Json Web Token.*** Also known as *JWT's*.

The process goes like this:

1. Get access token from other site to have permission to use the API from that site. Certain http headers, passwords, etc, are often included with this every single time data is exchanged.
2. Once you get a response giving you permission, you can now perform the type of request you want, with the data you want.

The data format for all this is USUALLY done with JSON. So you will have to import json, then `json.dumps(obj)` to turn it into valid json, and `json.loads(obj)` to turn your response into a python dictionary, so you can use it in your template, or wherever you want.

If you want to see an example of this, I recently made a [free GoFundMe clone](https://github.com/CyberHavenProgramming/fundraiser_app/blob/master/fundraiser_app/views.py) on my guthub. In the `donate()` view at the bottom, it uses the requests library, and shows how a JWT is obtained and used. You can see it there.